# stack or union multiple fields in MS Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

Beginner's question here... I have a table of tree measurements being 3 fields: - ID, Diameter_1, Diameter_2

& I wish to get to these 3 fields: - ID, DiameterName, DiameterMeasurement
[Input and Desired Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kwVwN.jpg)

```
SELECT DISTINCT ID, Diameter_1
FROM tblDiameters
UNION SELECT DISTINCT ID, Diameter_2
FROM tblDiameters;
```

Though it results in only 2 fields.  How may the field: - DiameterMeasurement be brought in?

Many thanks :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were on the right track to use a union.  Here is one viable approach:

```sql
SELECT ID, 'Diameter_1' AS DiameterName, Diameter_1 AS DiameterMeasurement
FROM tblDiameters
UNION ALL
SELECT ID, 'Diameter_2', Diameter_2
FROM tblDiameters
ORDER BY ID, DiameterName;
```

Comment: That's brilliant - thanks Tim!  This resulted in some null values, so I've excluded them with WHERE NOT clauses.  Best regards :-)